# help with this problem. I need to find $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

the exercise is =

Determine all real functions $f$ which satisfy :
$$
f(x-f(y))=f(x+y^{1999}) + f(f(y)+y^{1999}) +1
$$
for arbitrary real numbers $x,y$.

Information  of the exercise =  I found the solution of this problem in the [site](http://www.komal.hu/verseny/1999-11/A.h.shtml) but the solution is in Hungarian. However I understand all the steps to resolve the problem, except the last step, i.e.  I don't  understand why $f(x)$ is $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

I use what is proven (with the same notations) in the reference you have given.

a) I start with the fact that $h(y)$ is a polynomial in $y$. First we show that $g(0)$ is not zero. In fact, if $g(0)=f(0)=0$, then by (3) of your reference with $x=y=0$, we get $c=0$, hence $f(0)=-1$, a contradiction.

b)We know then that $h(y)$ is a polynomial of degree $1998$. Suppose that the leading coefficient of $h$ is positive. Then the image of $\mathbb{R}$ under $h$ contain an interval $[A,+\infty[$ for some $A$. For $z\geq A$, there exists $y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(y)=z$, and by the last formula of your reference, you have $f(x)=f(x+h(y))=f(x+z)$ for all $z\geq A$. In particular, you have $f(z)=f(0)$ for all $z\geq A$. Now for a $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $z\geq A$ such that $x+z\geq A$; hence $f(x)=f(0)$, and $f$ is constant. Same proof if the leading coeffcient of $h$ is negative.